# Syntax highlight works for gvim (GUI version of vim) but not for vim (terminal-based vim)

Tags: typescript, vim, vi, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am new to vim and I want to code in vim. I have installed the necessary plugins for syntax highlighting JSX in TypeScript and everything works fine for GUI version of Vim but not for terminal-based Vim. Please help me figure out the issue. below are the plugins that I am using for syntax highlighting.

1. For TypeScript: https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim
2. For JSX in TypeScript: https://github.com/peitalin/vim-jsx-typescript

I am using Vundle to install plugins. I tried to make some customization in the color as given in the README section of the second plugin mentioned above. According to that when I used `hi` command, it did not have any effect on terminal-based Vim but it worked perfectly fine on GUI based Vim. Also, if possible please point me towards any article/blog for a beginner to know more about vim and vimscript.

EDIT:

I am trying to setup syntax highlight for JSX in TypeScript for React Development and I have installed above plugins to achieve that. Below is the content of my .vimrc file.

```
set nocompatible                " choose no compatibility with legacy vi syntax enable
set encoding=utf-8
set showcmd                     " display incomplete commands
set t_Co=256
filetype plugin indent on       " load file type plugins + indentation

"" monkai theme
syntax enable
colorscheme monokai

set nu
set guifont=monacob\ bold\ 9

highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=gray
set colorcolumn=80

"" Whitespace
set nowrap                      " don't wrap lines
set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2      " a tab is two spaces (or set this to 4)
set expandtab                   " use spaces, not tabs (optinal)
set backspace=indent,eol,start  " backspace through everything in insert mode

"" Searching
set hlsearch                    " highlight matches
set incsearch                   " incremental searching
set ignorecase                  " searches are case insensitive...
set smartcase                   " ... unless they contain at least one capital letter

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp +=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive.git'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-rails'
Plugin 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
Plugin 'peitalin/vim-jsx-typescript'
" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" autocmd FileType typescript.tsx setlocal commentstring={/*\ %s\ */}
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tsx,*.jsx set filetype=typescript.tsx
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ts,*.js set filetype=typescript.jsx

" dark red
hi tsxTagName guifg=#E06C75

" orange
hi tsxCloseString guifg=#F99575
hi tsxCloseTag guifg=#F99575
hi tsxAttributeBraces guifg=#F99575
hi tsxEqual guifg=#F99575

" yellow
hi tsxAttrib guifg=#F8BD7F cterm=italic
```

Below is the screenshot of the JSX syntax highlight in GUI version of Vim
[image]

Below is the screenshot of the JSX syntax highlight in terminal version Vim
[image]

As we can see in the .vimrc and screenshots, the JSX tag colors etc.. declared at the end of the file are working fine for Gvim but not working for terminal-based vim. Please help me understand what wrong I am doing here.

Comment: What do you see? Why is it wrong? What do you expect to see? What did you do *exactly*?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> " dark red
> hi tsxTagName guifg=#E06C75
> ```

With the `guifg` attribute, you only define colors for GVIM.

Since Vim 8, there's the [`:help 'termguicolors'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27termguicolors%27) option; you can attempt to `:set termguicolors`; some terminals do support that.

Failing that, you have to separately define colors (from a limited color palette, depending on the number of available colors, which `:set t_Co?` will tell you) for the color terminal via the `ctermfg` / `ctermbg` attributes. For example:

```
hi tsxTagName guifg=#E06C75 ctermfg=DarkRed
```

#### Alternative approaches via plugins

Plugins like [CSApprox](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) can take the GUI color definitions and convert them to a closely matching 256-color `cterm` color palette for high-color terminals. This helps with colorschemes that otherwise only pick from the bland default 16-color terminal color palette, or only provide GUI color definitions.

Another approach is taken by [csexact](https://github.com/KevinGoodsell/vim-csexact), which modifies the (supported) terminal's palette to exactly match Vim's GUI colors.